# How to implement mailinator api to read mails from public inbox using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, mailinator

I am trying to read email contents from mailinator public inbox using Jmeter for my testing, but unable to understand the details I need to provide in the request.

Can anyone help me with designing the request sampler to get that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Message API](https://www.mailinator.com/docs/index.html#message-api) you basically you need to:

1. Send request to https://mailinator.com/api/v2/domains/private/inboxes/your-inbox-here
2. Extract the message ID you're looking for using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)
3. Send request to https://mailinator.com/api/v2/domains/private/messages/testinbox-1570635306-12914603
4. Extract the body using JSON Extractor
5. Do what you need with the body

Your Mailinator API token can be set via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), configure it to send [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the value of your token.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the end user agreement for your mail provider.   In most cases the use of automation other than supported mail clients is forbidden.  This is to prevent the use of automation to send spam messages.

Also, as you will be testing infrastructure not under your control, you will ned to obtain permission from the site owner.  You will need to respect their time windows for testing, as well as any restrictions on host, instance, volume, etc...

If you need a mail host involved in a performance test, consider setting up your own email server to receive messages and then pull the messages from a server you own, manage, and control.